# where to stick libraries I install myself?

Tags: compiling, directory, make, ffmpeg, configure

In building `ffmpeg` from source, I got the following error to `./configure --with-libcelt`:

```
ERROR: libcelt not found
```

So I went to http://www.celt-codec.org/downloads/, cloned the repo, and `./autogen.sh; ./configure; make; make install; make check`ed it.

Back to `ffmpeg` source directory, `./configure --with-libcelt` again gave the same error.

I tried soft-linking `/opt/celt/libcelt/celt.h` into `/usr/local/lib`, but I am now officially stabbing in the dark.

---

I thought `/usr/local/lib` is the canonical place a `./configure` package would look for a library, and that the main named `.h`eader file would be enough to show the configurator where things are. What's the right answer?

Comment: A notice above the celt download page says that the codec is obsolete and has been merged with Opus. Any particular reason you are keen for this?

Answer (score 0):

Header files, among other things, tell the compiler what functions, values, etc. exist in a library. Just because you point to the header file it doesn't mean that the linker will know where to look for the corresponding library.  `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` are normally used when installing third party programs. Now, `/opt` is usually used for programs untar into one folder.

From what I can see you have celt in the `/opt/celt` folder. Look for there for a file that looks something like `libcelt.so`. That is were you need to point the linker to. Assuming the file is somewhere in there, then you can point the linker to look into that folder by updating the library path variable as such:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/celt:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then run your configure and make scripts again. You may need to start a clean installation.